# How can I connect (ssh) to docker container from other computer inside my lab network?

Tags: docker, networking, containers

I'm trying to use the resources from other computers using the python3-mpi4py since my research uses a lot of calculations.

My codes and data are on the docker container.
To use mpi I have to be able to ssh directly to the docker container from other computers inside the same network as the host computer is located. But I cannot ssh into it.

my image is like below

```
|Host               |  <- On the same network  -> | Other Computers |  
|   port 10000      |                             |                 |
|       ^           |                             |                 |
|-------|-----------|                             |                 |  
|       V           |                             |                 |
|   port 10000      |                             |                 |
|docker container <-|------------ ssh ------------|-->              |
```

Can anyone teach me how to do this?

Comment: Maybe ssh onto the the host machine, then ssh into the container. That is, assuming that you have ssh running inside the container. But, if you ssh onto the host, there are other ways at getting inside it.

Comment: But, why are you doing this? You should have a path on the container mounted on a path on the host and be using that as your working directory, so that a) you can use those resources outside the container, or even run multiple containers using the same resources, or, even, access those resources over the network without going through the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can running ssh server in the `Host` computer, then you can ssh to `Host`,  then use docker command such as `docker exec -i -t containerName /bin/bash` to get interactive shell.

example:

```
# 1. On Other Computers 
ssh root@host_ip

>> enter into Host ssh shell

# 2. On Host ssh shell
docker exec -i -t containerName /bin/bash

>> enter into docker interactive shell

# 3. On docker interactive shell
do sth.
```

Comment: Playfully, you can use ssh enter into HostA, and use ssh enter into HostB in HostA ssh shell, and enter into other one unceasingly...